# Gatsby set sass lint

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gatsby, lint

I want sass linter in Gatsby's project

```
plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
      },
    },

    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-eslint",
      options: {
       
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`
  ],
```

How to include it?
I want to detect incorrect CSS rules etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESlint is a JavaScript linter, so it can't analyze nor lint your Sass code.

However, you can use [Stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/awesome-stylelint) to parse SCSS, Saas, or CSS files.

You can follow the default configuration steps in [their GitHub](https://github.com/primer/stylelint-config):

1. Install it by:

   ```
   npm install --save --dev @primer/stylelint-config
   ```
2. Add a `stylelintrc.json` file in the root of your project (it can be a `.yml` or `.js` format too if needed)
3. Add your configuration rules. You can inherit from the default ones by using the `extends` rule as:

   ```
   {
    "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
    "rules": {
      "indentation": "tab",
      "number-leading-zero": null
    }
   }
   ```
4. Customize your commands to trigger your lint rules (change the file extension accordingly):

   ```
   npx stylelint "**/*.css"
   ```

Resources:

- https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started
- https://dev.to/stories_of_ren/switching-from-sass-lint-to-stylelint-5f8c